# LiteTouch WinPE x64 file shows up as x86 Architecture

Tags: deployment, mdt

recently at my new job I have been setting up a deployment server to decrease the time we spend imaging our machines. After installing `WDS` and getting everything else online, I noticed when I go to import the built `LiteTouch` images in the Server Manager, that the `LiteTouchPE_x64.wim` file is imported as an `x86` architecture.

I have tested my `x86` deployment and it works fine, but when I boot the machine into my `x64` deployment image, I get a fault error `0xC000035a` (CPU Not detected as 64 bit).

Now, I enabled the architecture discovery for `WDS` and triple checked through Intel's ARK website to ensure my CPU is in fact 64 bit capable, this is probably the last thing that might be giving me issues (I wouldn't think unsigned drivers could give me issues, I downloaded a .cab file from Dell geared towards my WinPE version (Dell Latitude E6510 is the test machine) and I'm running `2008 R2`.

I should note that the base .iso I added to the Install Images folder for our deployment share was a All In One Version of Windows that I built by hand (that works). I guess I could download a `x64` iso from Digital River and see if that does anything.

Comment: Am I right to assume that your question is why this error might be occuring?

Comment: Yes, apologies. I just find it odd that I'd import a Litetouch .wim file that's geared for 64 bit imaging is presented as an x86 architecture.